# ADE not navigating pages in HP Pavilion laptop

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to read a DRM protected PDF file in Adobe Digital Edition 4.5.11 in Windows 10 box. The laptop is HP Pavilion. The files are getting opened in ADE but when I try to navigate using arrow keys or Pg Up, Pg Dn keys the page no gets incremented but the contents of that page are not visible. This is weird because the same PDF gets opened on another system.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the probable reason. ADE is not comfortable with Surface tablets or touch screen laptops. My Pavilion is a touch screen laptop, therefore ADE freezes during navigation.